# No ethernet device detected

Tags: ethernet

I'm trying to setup Archlinux on VMWare Workstation and for some reason I cannot find my ethernet card.

In lspci | grep Ethernet it says

```
Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
```

However in ip link it only lists

```
1: lo <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode  DEFAULT group default
link/loopback 00:00 ... brd 00:00 ...
```

I know that I should enable the ethernet controller through dhcpcd but it doesn't show within ip link or ifconfig as they only list the loopback device.

Why isn't showing up as eth0 or enoXXXX? And how do I fix this?

Comment: Check whether you have e1000e kernel module available (`lsmod|grep e1000e; modprobe e1000e; lsmod|grep e1000e`) or CONFIG_E1000E in /boot/config-$(uname -r).

Comment: @sourcejedi in lsmod I have e1000, e1000e and PTP. modproble only works with e1000. On e1000e it does nothing.

Comment: Sounds like you've covered that then, the driver module has already been loaded and you still have no eth0.  I don't quite understand your answer - if `lsmod` already shows the modules `modprobe` won't do anything for any of them.  And only three modules in `lsmod`? surprising.  It's possible e1000 and e1000e conflict (they can do & e1000 is somewhat deprecated)... I'm not sure it would cause this failure though.  Hmm if the modules are loaded, they may warn if they don't like the device, do check the kernel boot log (`dmesg` command) for messages from either module if you haven't already.

Comment: @sourcejedi I did check it, no errors as I see. Isn't there any way to force install, reinstall or something? Rescan for devices?

Comment: Rescan happens from scratch each boot.  (There's no records like on Windows).  I don't have any more productive suggestions, sorry - my main idea was to make sure you weren't running a custom kernel that lacked the driver.  Next level of blind refreshing would be the package that installed the kernel / module files - not sure about the commands as I don't use Arch.  If you struggle to work with them it might be simpler to start by re-validating the md5sum of the live ISO, boot from that & see whether ethernet is working.  I guess this is a recent install so the kernel will be about the same.